# Chrome extension: Different contextMenus on whether or not a word selection is made

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I am trying to display different contextMenus in my chrome extension based on whether or not text selection has been made. Any ideas on how to do this?

I want this code when no text is selected

```
chrome.contextMenus.create({
    title: "Not selected",
    contexts:["all"],  // ContextType
    onclick: search // A callback function
});
```

I want this code when text IS selected

```
chrome.contextMenus.create({
    title: "Selected",
    contexts:["all"],  // ContextType
    onclick: search // A callback function
});
```

Comment: 1. Try registering a different function for the `selection` context 2. additionally replace `all` with an explicit [list of contexts](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contextMenus#type-ContextType) except `selection` and `all`  2. see [Creating dynamic context menu in Chrome Extension is failing](//stackoverflow.com/q/13202896)

Comment: it worked! Thank you!